# meaning: raise meat vs. raise beef/pork

Tags: idiomatic-language

"Raise meat" means "raise cattle (or other animals?) to be slaughtered for their meat." Can we say "raise beef" or "raise pork"?

Answer (score 1):

Usually we have different names for animals and the meat produced from them. We raise cattle and pigs, and the final meat products are beef and pork respectively. To talk, in general, about raising unspecified animals for meat we can, however, say "raise meat".

[Pig or Pork? Cow or Beef?](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/words-and-their-stories-pig-or-pork-cow-or-beef/4104856.html)

Comment: however the person who raises meat might be a "beef farmer" or a "pig farmer" for no logical reasons.

Comment: I would say *raise **animals** (for food)*. I don't think I've ever heard anybody say *raise* ***meat*** before. Hearing that phase makes me think of hydroponic tanks with wires connected to chunks of meat floating in a solution. I wouldn't recommend that phrase to anyone.

Comment: But there is a pun that goes like this: Three brothers went out West to establish a cattle ranch, but couldn't think of an appropriate name for it. So they wrote to their father back East, and he replied, "Call it Focus, for that's where the sun's rays meet."